# How to do in-line labels

Tags: css

I want the date to appear in front of the label instead of under.I'm using bootstrap if that helps.

[image]

```html
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
        
        <div class="container"
        <div class="row">
            <label>End System Date:</label>
            <h4>1 Jul 2017</h4>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Cheat: `<h4 style="display:inline" >1 Jul 2017</h4>`

Answer (score 1):

Set the `display` property of the `h4` in your code.

```css
.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <label>End System Date:</label>
    <h4 class="inline-block">1 Jul 2017</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```